# Using standard image file format to work in all OS

Tags: java, image, cross-platform

I am new in Java.  I want develop a desktop application that work on all operating systems.  I want use a lot of pictures in my Application.

What is format of image that will work on all operating systems without change?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can easily Google this...anyway, JPG, GIF and PNG will work most anywhere.

Comment: Those types are pretty much guaranteed by the JVM (according to the tutorial).  For the full range supported on any platform, see `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()`.. but for this use stick to JPG, GIF and PNG.  I prefer PNG for icons, as it is non-lossy (unlike JPG) and supports more than 256 colors & partial transparency (unlike GIF).

Comment: I do prefer PNG myself for the reasons you stated. But it is surprising about the comment below, that BMP is supported on non-Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers did not include proof links, so... From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

> Image I/O has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP

Comment: Huh, I am surprised that BMP/WBMP is supported on non-Windows!  I would not use either format for icons though, see my comment to Mark M for why I'd use PNG.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: BMP is very popular, simple, and, according to wikipedia, free of patents, so why not include it? But I agree, I see no reasons of using it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was developed by MS (& was **proprietary**).

Comment: I don't know what you interpret as a "proof", but the excerpt from the tutorial does not mean anything but "the Oracle VM has built-in support for ...". The ImageIO specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/title.fm.html does not mandate support for specific formats.

Comment: @jarnbjo: why so pedantic? :) The fact that oracle in their tutorial promises that these formats are supported means that I can rely that these formats will be supported. Given such abstract request from the OP, I seriously doubt he meant J9 or JRocket, or gcj or whatever else implementation that might not include these plugins.